# cannot launch inkscape in windows subsystem for ubuntu

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, inkscape

I installed inkscape in windows subsystem for ubuntu by:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:inkscape.dev/stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install inkscape
```

After the installation, I could launch inkscape, even I tried to set up the stack size with "ulimit -s *stack size*". It always shows the error as below:

```
$ inkscape &
Wrong __data_start/_end pair
$ inkscape --version
Wrong __data_start/_end pair
Aborted (core dumped)
$ inkscape --help
Wrong __data_start/_end pair
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Does anyone meet the same problem? I tried very hard to solve this problem but I failed every time. Can any expert in inkscape help me? Thanks a lot!

Comment: A very good, tested version of inkscape is already in the Ubuntu repositories. Adding a PPA is not necessary for most users.

Comment: I have also tried to install inkscape based on your suggestion, still when launching it, the same problem arises. I am wondering maybe this is a new bug for inkscape?

Comment: Perhaps it's a bug in inkscape, perhaps it's a bug in WSL. I suggest reporting the bug against both

Comment: Is this WSL or WSL2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does not seem to be due to `stack size` as some other solutions from the past state. There are multiple open issues for this when it comes to Ubuntu > 18.04:

https://gitlab.com/inkscape/inkscape/-/issues/1420
https://gitlab.com/inkscape/inkscape/-/issues/1458

The beauty of WSL is it's easy to set up another distro. I installed 18.04 and was up and running with working `inkscape` very quickly.

As of Windows version 2004, you can also switch to WSL2. I have Ubuntu 20.04 and `inkscape` is working in WSL2.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl2-kernel

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. I followed your instruction, it really works in my laptop. I installed inkscape version 0.92.3 in ubuntu 18.04.